# Laravel - Having a hasMany() as well as a hasOne() relationship on the same model?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I've got a `Company` model in which I would like to define two relationships with the `User` model:

```
  public function users(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }

  public function administrator(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'superuserid');
  }
```

I have a `superuserid` field in my `companies` table in the database, which is a foreign key to the `id` of the `users` table.

I just want to know if this is at all a good strategy or even possible?

Comment: Your concept is perfectly fine.

Comment: You might consider using `superuser_id` and you might consider as first parameter using `App\User::class` instead of string, apart that you can have 10 relationships between two models.

Comment: @Kyslik, why would you suggest using the first parameter that way?

Comment: Your IDE might like it.

Comment: Can we call `Company::find(1)->with('users', 'administrator')`? Is it ok in the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a good strategy and it is possible.

In your model you can define as much relations as your model needs. And those relations can be of different types (hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, etc).

In your case, since the company has multiple users and belongs to a super user, we have two different relations, so, obviously, we need to create two methods in the model to represent these two relations.

Another example: the relation between you and your father. Let's say that there is this implementation of a User model:

```
class User extends Model
{

  public function children()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id_parent');
  }

  public function dad()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_parent')->where('gender', 'male');
  }

}
```

Here a User can has many children but belongs to just one dad.